# How to add an image to fixed navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I want to add an image to a fixed navigation bar that is bigger than its height. How do i put the image in there and add a border without it being cut off. i want the image to be fixed aswell.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/2btrY/2/)

```
Thank you
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Quentin are you saying it's a bad idea to use jsfiddle? and does the link you pointed out apply to jsfiddle as well (ie as well as to random user specific websites.. which was the focus of the answer)

Comment: No, it's a great idea to use JSFiddle. It just isn't a good idea to make it impossible to understand the question if JSFiddle goes away.

Comment: Yes a lot of that applies... though the link is to a specific reduced problem (it's not the whole site), the question doesn't make sense without the link. If the OP could clarify how they would like the image positioned inside the bar, that would be useful.

Comment: aligned on the left. i don't want it to be cut of. i dont want the entire bar to be resized, just the image so it sticks out of the bar similar to this http://www.awwwards.com/gallery/3098/40-websites-with-fixed-navigation and http://www.awwwards.com/gallery/3092/40-websites-with-fixed-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the height of the image , the browser will automatically set the proportionate width

```
           <img src="images/myimage.jpg"  height="50px" />
```

Here I put 50px , use whatever will fit in the navigation bar